# Error 3343 in MS Access - Unrecognizable database format

Tags: database, ms-access

We are running access 2016 32 bit
Subscription Product is Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus
Version  1708 (Build 8431.2250)
Microsoft Access 2016 MSO (16.0.8431.2110) 32 bit

We are  experiencing the dreaded: **database is in an unrecognized format** error.

This has started happening intermittently, usually several times a day.

The system is split between  several databases on the back end and a client on the front end.
Code is not compiled and a copy lives on each client's workstation. We have 5 people working on FE client workstations who interact with the databases through a network.

We had all of our databases as **mdb**'s. We were having many locking and slowing down issues and so we **tried moving up to accdb** databases. Very soon after, various FE users started getting the "database is in an unrecognized format" at all different times of the day, during regular use. A Compact and Repair fixes the issue, but is just a quick plaster until the next time.

We have now tried various combinations with no success:

- client accdb  format and backend dbs accdb format;
- client accdb format and all backend dbs  mdb format;
- and back to client mdb and backend mdb dbs format

Is anything wrong with the 1708 build? 
I see the issue with the 1710 build is very similar to what we are experiencing.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_winother-mso_2016/access-build-1710-seems-to-break-compatibility/22d98398-12fd-4c42-8a48-ac2f9fb97695

All help will be very appreciated!